# wpf ListView item expand at mouseover

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a ListView with pretty long listelement at times. I would like to create an event, where if I drag the mouse over an element, the whole name appears in a tooltip-like small window with the whole text of the item. This way the user can read it even if it is too long for the ListView window width.

I am a bit stuck, because I find no MouseOver event for the ListView elements. I would probably have to go on with a custom Style for my ListView, but I don't have experience with Styles.

I would really appreciate a little help, to get me started!

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AttachedProperty` for MouseMove and hook your list view with the property. The attached property can be used to any element in your application.

> Attached Property

```
public class MouseBehaviour
{
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseMoveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseMoveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MouseMoveCommandChanged)));

    private static void MouseMoveCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;

        element.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(element_MouseMove);
    }

    static void element_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        ICommand command = GetMouseMoveCommand(element);

        command.Execute(e);
    }

    public static void SetMouseMoveCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetMouseMoveCommand(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ICommand)element.GetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty);
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
xmlns:mousebehav="clr-namespace:your namespace"

<ListView mousebehav:MouseBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}">
```

### VM

```
private RelayCommand _MouseMoveCommand;
    public RelayCommand MouseMoveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_MouseMoveCommand== null) return _MouseMoveCommand= new RelayCommand(param => Execute_MouseMoveCommand((MouseEventArgs)param));
            return _MouseMoveCommand;
        }
        set { _MouseMoveCommand= value; }
    }

private void Execute_MouseMoveCommand(MouseEventArgs param)
    {
        //your logic to expand or ??
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. After a few hours of experimenting, I managed to solve it quite compact from the xaml:

```
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
             <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```