# Mouseover button binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

What technique could be used in `WPF` to show `TextBlock` `Text` based on the `Button` that has mouse over on it?

[image]

The UI is organized as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Item1" Tag="This is the text for Item1"/>
        <Button Content="Item2" Tag="This is the text for Item2"/>
        <Button Content="Item3" Tag="This is the text for Item3"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This text should be shown based on the mouseovered button"/>
</Grid>
```

I was thinking to set the desired text to `Tag` of the `Button` but how to get that Tag to show on the mouse over event.

Notes:

- I prefer to use individual `Buttons` here instead of `ListBox` or any other `ItemsControl` (the real application has more controls between these things etc.)
- The application follows MVVM
- I would prefer an approach other that setting the texts to UI directly (`Tag` of the `Button`)

Comment: This will help...http://stackoverflow.com/a/31834789/2470362 

Instead of ListView you can keep your button.

Comment: I created the behaviour and binded each Button to the Command. Now the next question is how to understand which Button raised the command so that I can get the Tag information. The command will execute this public void UpdateText(MouseEventArgs param)
{
 //How to get access to the Button that raised the event here ?
}

Comment: you have `MouseEventArgs param` will tell you ie: `param.OriginalSource`

Comment: param.OriginalSource returns TextBlock. Is it correct to get its TemplatedParent to access the Button that has the Tag ?

Comment: Then the last problem is when the mouse is not anymore over any of the Buttons, I need to be able to set the viewmodel property that returns the text to empty String. The linked example you sent doesnt show how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For Mouse Move over,

Create an AttachedProperty for MouseMove and hook your list view with the property. The attached property can be used to any element in your application.

Attached Property

```
public class MouseBehaviour
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseMoveCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseMoveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MouseMoveCommandChanged)));

private static void MouseMoveCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;

    element.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(element_MouseMove);
}

static void element_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;

    ICommand command = GetMouseMoveCommand(element);

    command.Execute(e);
}

public static void SetMouseMoveCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
{
    element.SetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty, value);
}

public static ICommand GetMouseMoveCommand(UIElement element)
{
    return (ICommand)element.GetValue(MouseMoveCommandProperty);
}
}
```

### XAML

```
xmlns:mousebehav="clr-namespace:your namespace"

<Button mousebehav:MouseBehaviour.MouseMoveCommand="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}">
```

### VM

```
private RelayCommand _MouseMoveCommand;
public RelayCommand MouseMoveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_MouseMoveCommand== null) return _MouseMoveCommand= new RelayCommand(param => Execute_MouseMoveCommand((MouseEventArgs)param));
        return _MouseMoveCommand;
    }
    set { _MouseMoveCommand= value; }
}

private void Execute_MouseMoveCommand(MouseEventArgs param)
{
    //your logic to expand or ??
}
```

> Attached property for Mouse Leave,

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseLeaveCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseLeaveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MouseLeaveCommandChanged)));

    private static void MouseLeaveCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;

        element.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(element_MouseLeave);
    }

    static void element_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        ICommand command = GetMouseLeaveCommand(element);

        command.Execute(e);
    }

    public static void SetMouseLeaveCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MouseLeaveCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetMouseLeaveCommand(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ICommand)element.GetValue(MouseLeaveCommandProperty);
    }
```

### VM

```
private RelayCommand _MouseLeaveCommand;
public RelayCommand MouseLeaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_MouseLeaveCommand== null) return _MouseLeaveCommand= new RelayCommand(param => Execute_MouseLeaveCommand((MouseEventArgs)param));
        return _MouseLeaveCommand;
    }
    set { _MouseMoveCommand= value; }
}

private void Execute_MouseLeaveCommand(MouseEventArgs param)
{
    //your logic to expand or ??
}
```

### XAML

```
<Button mousebehav:MouseBehaviour.MouseLeaveCommand="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}">
```